# Compare two lists - Scala

Tags: scala

what is the best way to verify the greater list value using scala?

example:

Verify if `List(1, 2, 3)` is greater than `List(2, 3, 4)`

I tried create a function:

`def listGt[T](li:List[T], l2:List[T]) = li > l2`

but I got a message: error: value > is not a member of List[T]

Comment: You need the list `size`.

Comment: @LimbSoup The `size` function returns the list length. I'm trying to create a function like the clojure `compare` (http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/compare).

Comment: I see. It wasn't clear what you meant by "list value".  In that case, you can use `sum` for numeric types. For other types you'd need to define what `sum` meant.

Comment: Ok @LimbSoup, scala is new to me and I think my question is bad. Let me try again: There are some way to create a function like the clojure `compare` (http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/compare) using scala?

Comment: What exactly does "greater than" mean for lists according to you? There's no obvious way how one list is "greater than" another list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [complex reasons](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4097?focusedCommentId=51922&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-51922), you have to do an import before comparing `List` and many other collections:

```
import Ordering.Implicits._
```

Once you do so life is happy:

```
List(1) < List(2) // true
List(List(2), List(1)).sorted // swaps order as expected
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare lengths of 3D vectors the following may return not what you want:

```
import Ordering.Implicits._
println(List(2, 3, 4) > List(-2, -3, -4)) // prints true, but lengths are equal
```

May be this will suit:

```
object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val res = listGt(List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, 4))
    println(res) // false
    val res2 = listGt(List(2, 3, 4), List(1, 2, 3))
    println(res2) // true
  }

  implicit def coordsToLength[T <% Double](li: List[T]) = math.sqrt(li.foldLeft(0.0)(_ + math.pow(_, 2)))

  def listGt[T <% Double](li: List[T], l2: List[T]) = li > l2
}
```